# How can i upload a media file to my google drive using google api?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Hey im trying to upload certain media files to my google drive using google api services can someone please tell me how can i do it, in my previous question i have given the code for getservice and clientservice you could refer to that  thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a file to Google drive is reasonably strait forward.

1. authorize the user.
2. create the file metadata
3. upload the file data itself

I have serval tutorials on this topic and a YouTube video  This should get you started.
[How to upload a file to Google Drive with C# .net](https://www.daimto.com/upload-file-to-google-drive/)

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

// Installed file credentials from google developer console.
const string credentialsJson = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\credentials.json";

// used to store authorization credentials.
var userName = "user";

// scope of authorization needed from the user
var scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

// file to upload

var filePath = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Data\image.png";
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
var folderToUploadTo = "1hwRZWAi-OznYGL51Yx9BJmDp5Ayips16";


var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(credentialsJson).Secrets,
    scopes,
    userName,
    CancellationToken.None).Result;


// Create the  Drive service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Daimto Drive upload Quickstart"
});


// Upload file photo.jpg on drive.
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
{
    Name = fileName,
    Parents = new List<string>() { folderToUploadTo }
};

var fsSource = File.OpenRead(filePath);

// Create a new file, with metadatafileName and stream.
var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "image/jpeg");
request.Fields = "id";

var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
}

// the file id of the new file we created
var fileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;

Console.WriteLine($"fileId {fileId}");

Console.ReadLine();
```